# How to get pylint and black working together in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been trying to get pylint and black working together on VSCode without success.

I can get either one working but only if the other isn't (i.e. black will format but nothing will be reported by pylint, or pylint will report errors but running 'Format Code' does nothing).

Here's my setttings.json:

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": false,
    "editor.formatOnType": false,
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintPath": "/usr/bin/pylint-3",
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": false,
    "python.linting.flake8Path": "/usr/bin/flake8-3",
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "python.formatting.blackPath": "/usr/bin/black",
    "python.formatting.blackArgs": [
        "--line-length=110"
    ],
    "python.unitTest.pyTestEnabled": true,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
    "workbench.settings.editor": "json",
    "python.linting.enabled": true
}
```

Environment:

- Fedora 29
- VSCode 1.28.2
- Python extension 2018.9.2
- pylint 2.1.1
- black 18.6b4

Comment: any success getting this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this before no success. Neither did `flake8` + `autopep8` if my memory serves me right. And now I won't even be able to install the two of them in the same `pipenv` virtual environment due to some dependency conflicts. If you are interested you can examine the output below.

Currently, I use `pylint`+`autopep8` (default by VS Code) and if you would like to stick with `black` I guess you need to switch your linter to something else.

```
// I have pylint installed already
➜ pipenv install --dev autopep8 
Installing autopep8…
Adding autopep8 to Pipfile's [dev-packages]…
✔ Installation Succeeded 
Pipfile.lock (3830f9) out of date, updating to (6cacd5)…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
✘ Locking Failed! 
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/xzhan/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 69, in resolve
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=requirements_dir
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/xzhan/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 726, in resolve_deps
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=req_dir,
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/xzhan/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 480, in actually_resolve_deps
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       resolved_tree = resolver.resolve()
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/xzhan/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 395, in resolve
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure: ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches black
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       Skipped pre-versions: 18.3a0, 18.3a0, 18.3a1, 18.3a1, 18.3a2, 18.3a2, 18.3a3, 18.3a3, 18.3a4, 18.3a4, 18.4a0, 18.4a0, 18.4a1, 18.4a1, 18.4a2, 18.4a2, 18.4a3, 18.4a3, 18.4a4, 18.4a4, 18.5b0, 18.5b0, 18.5b1, 18.5b1, 18.6b0, 18.6b0, 18.6b1, 18.6b1, 18.6b2, 18.6b2, 18.6b3, 18.6b3, 18.6b4, 18.6b4, 18.9b0, 18.9b0, 19.3b0, 19.3b0
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches black
Skipped pre-versions: 18.3a0, 18.3a0, 18.3a1, 18.3a1, 18.3a2, 18.3a2, 18.3a3, 18.3a3, 18.3a4, 18.3a4, 18.4a0, 18.4a0, 18.4a1, 18.4a1, 18.4a2, 18.4a2, 18.4a3, 18.4a3, 18.4a4, 18.4a4, 18.5b0, 18.5b0, 18.5b1, 18.5b1, 18.6b0, 18.6b0, 18.6b1, 18.6b1, 18.6b2, 18.6b2, 18.6b3, 18.6b3, 18.6b4, 18.6b4, 18.9b0, 18.9b0, 19.3b0, 19.3b0
There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies.
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=requirements_dir
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/xzhan/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 726, in resolve_deps
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=req_dir,
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/xzhan/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 480, in actually_resolve_deps
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       resolved_tree = resolver.resolve()
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/xzhan/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 395, in resolve
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure: ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches black
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       Skipped pre-versions: 18.3a0, 18.3a0, 18.3a1, 18.3a1, 18.3a2, 18.3a2, 18.3a3, 18.3a3, 18.3a4, 18.3a4, 18.4a0, 18.4a0, 18.4a1, 18.4a1, 18.4a2, 18.4a2, 18.4a3, 18.4a3, 18.4a4, 18.4a4, 18.5b0, 18.5b0, 18.5b1, 18.5b1, 18.6b0, 18.6b0, 18.6b1, 18.6b1, 18.6b2, 18.6b2, 18.6b3, 18.6b3, 18.6b4, 18.6b4, 18.9b0, 18.9b0, 19.3b0, 19.3b0
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches black
Skipped pre-versions: 18.3a0, 18.3a0, 18.3a1, 18.3a1, 18.3a2, 18.3a2, 18.3a3, 18.3a3, 18.3a4, 18.3a4, 18.4a0, 18.4a0, 18.4a1, 18.4a1, 18.4a2, 18.4a2, 18.4a3, 18.4a3, 18.4a4, 18.4a4, 18.5b0, 18.5b0, 18.5b1, 18.5b1, 18.6b0, 18.6b0, 18.6b1, 18.6b1, 18.6b2, 18.6b2, 18.6b3, 18.6b3, 18.6b4, 18.6b4, 18.9b0, 18.9b0, 19.3b0, 19.3b0
There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies.
```

Comment: pipenv uninstall black, pipenv clean, pipenv lock --clear, pipenv install black==19.10b0 (or whatever current version there is at the time you read this).  Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

I think part of the secret sauce is to disable certain pylint warnings which conflict with black ("disable = ...")

Add the file .pylintrc in root:

```
# Looks like setup.cfg cannot load the extensions in the precommit,
# but that the pylintrc file can
# This happens even when specifying --rcfile=setup.cfg
# Possible bug from pylint?
[MASTER]
load-plugins = pylint.extensions.docparams, pylint.extensions.docstyle, pylint.extensions.mccabe

[BASIC]
accept-no-param-doc = no
accept-no-raise-doc = no
accept-no-return-doc = no
accept-no-yields-doc = no
default-docstring-type = numpy

[FORMAT]
max-line-length = 88

[MESSAGES CONTROL]
disable = C0330, C0326, C0199, C0411
```